# Getting error while calling function from element attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying for creating multiple progress bar with dynamic value

```
<progressbar class="progress-striped active"  value="{{getValue(value.currentStatus)}}"
  type="{{getType(this.value, value.currentStatus)}}">
    {{ value.currentStatus }}
</progressbar>
```

following two functions are called above, but getType function is called and working
 but getValue function is not called its throw error

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'getValue' is unexpected, 
>   expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression
>   [{{getValue(value.currentStatus)}}]  starting at
>   [getValue(value.currentStatus)}}]

```
$scope.getValue = function(Status) {

        var tasksLength = 4;
        var completedActions;

        if (Status != null) {
             completedActions = completedActions + 1;
        }

        var progressActions = (completedActions == tasksLength) ? 0 : 1;

        var queuedActions = tasksLength - (completedActions + progressActions);

        return Math.ceil(((queuedActions * 0.09) + (progressActions * 0.35) +
                    completedActions) / tasksLength * 100);
    }

    $scope.getType = function(value, Status) {

        if ((value > 80) && (Status == "FAILED")) {
            type = 'danger';
        } else if (value > 80) {
            type = 'success';
        } else if (value > 50) {
            type = 'warning';
        } else {
            type = 'info';
        }
        return type;
    }
```

please help me to solve this error

Comment: Probably it's not the cause here, but shouldn't there be `;` after functions' closing `}` (in the model/controller code)?

Comment: I think that you can't create function inside `{{ }}` that's only for values, you need to create directive here that will handle progress, it can be `.directive('progressbar',`.